# Invariant factors for finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I wish to find the invariant factors for the finite, abelian group:
$B = \Bbb{Z}_6 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{100} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{45}$
of the order $2^3 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^3 = 27000$.

I have prior to this only been used to finding invariant factors for standard abelian groups of the form i.e. $A = \Bbb{Z}_{p^2 q} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{p} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{qr}$ of the order $p^3 q^2 r$.

I know that for a group of order $x$, the elementary divisors are all combinations of the prime factors and the invariant factors are the combinations of these prime factors, when all co-prime numbers are multiplied from elementary divisors, but I'm not sure how to attack this problem, with this information.

Can anybody drop a hint?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to split each factor in $B$ into $p$-groups:
$$
B = \Bbb{Z}_6 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{100} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{45}
\cong \Bbb{Z}_2 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{25} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{9} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{5}
$$

Now list the powers of each prime in increasing order right justified and multiply them vertically (again using the Chinese Remainder Theorem):
\begin{array}{r}
2 & 4 \\
3 & 9 \\
5 & 25 \\
\hline
30 & 900 \\
\end{array}
This gives the invariant factors $\Bbb{Z}_{30} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{900}$.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1874240/589

Comment: I don't understand why this. Where can I learn more about this method?

Comment: @Shaun, it's just the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: That's not what I recognise as the Chinese Remainder Theorem, I'm afraid. I've seen versions of it for groups, sure, but right now I don't see it here. Right: I need to revise it.